# how to conda pack the base env

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I know the commands:

```
# Pack environment my_env into my_env.tar.gz
$ conda pack -n my_env

# Pack environment my_env into out_name.tar.gz
$ conda pack -n my_env -o out_name.tar.gz

# Pack environment located at an explicit path into my_env.tar.gz
$ conda pack -p /explicit/path/to/my_env
```

are used to pack the environment named as `my_env`.

But, how to `conda pack` the **base** env of the anaconda?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Anyway, why do you want to do that?

Comment: I just want to move the already env from one machine to another and I only use the base env.

Comment: Did you find a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

How about making a clone of the base env first?
**conda create --name baseclone --clone base**

There is some packages that cannot be cloned though, don't know if it is a critical issue: (The following packages cannot be cloned out of the root environment.. blablabla)

Then the cloned env you just created can be packed by the conda pack command.